# How to update/replace value in the dictionary/json file where the value of the dictionary's key type is list using robot framework

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary, robotframework

I am trying to update the value "Four" to "four"

**json format:**

```
"Num" : {
        "Roman": [
        {
            "word_rep": {
                "IV": [
                    "Four"
                ]
            }
        }
        ]
    }
```

**code:**

```
${file}    Get File    file1.json
${json_file}    Evaluate    json.loads('''${file}''')    json
${new_val}   set variable   four
set to dictionary      ${json_file["Num"]['Roman'][0]['word_rep']}        IV[0]=${new_val}
```

When I try the above code i am getting a new dictionary added({'IV[0]':'four'}) to the existing dictionary
I want to replace the value and not new addition.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you try to use a dictionary keyword to update a list.
I.e. Robot Framework will treat `IV[0]` as a string, and since the key don't exist it will set it to the dictionary as a new entry.

To update the list you need to refer to it as a list with [Set List Value](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20List%20Value).
Below should work accordingly.
`Set List Value      ${json_file["Num"]['Roman'][0]['word_rep']['IV']}    0    ${new_val}`